# Dynamic datetime in Dart with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have an app which displays the current date in a format e.g. '18 September 2019'.

How can I have this date update automatically when the day rolls over while my app is still open or running in the background?

The Dart DateTime class documentation says the datetime object value cannot be changed once created.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Timer** class to update your DateTime automatically day rolls.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(days: 1), (Timer t) => setState((){
//write your code to show DateTime
}));
```